# TFS throws Error after CheckIn - hexadecimal value is an invalid character

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs

As described in title, after checking into TFS, the following error is thrown:

> '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line1, position
>   1.

Any one know how to resolve this issue?

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SleI.png)

Comment: What file type are you checking in? Have you looked in the actual file content? If it's something like an XML file and it contains NULL characters, then that might be the cause.

Comment: Did you have multiple files or single file in the pending change during the check in? If you have multiple files, suggest you check in separately, to narrow down the special file.